# Magento 2, ¿como saber los nombres de los bloques?

Tags: xml, layout, magento2

Estoy buscando la manera de saber los nombres de los bloques para poder modificarlos, en si quiero cambiarles la ubicación a los bloques.

Estoy trabajando en `Magento_catalog`.

El que tenga buenos conocimientos en Magento 2, en como cambiar totalmente el diseño del theme pero haciendo uso de los recursos de Magento, me serviría de mucho la ayuda, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para saber los nombres de los bloques no existe ninguna forma sencilla incluida en Magento, tendrías que instalar una extensión como esta:

https://github.com/cedcommerce/Magento2-Developer-Debug-Tool

---

Una forma que utilizo para determinar los nombres de los bloques sin usar esta extensión es:

1. Mostrar las rutas de los templates de cada bloque, activando:

   > Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enable Template Path Hints for Storefront > Yes
2. Después de encontrar el nombre del template del bloque que estoy buscando, hago una búsqueda de la ruta de dicho template entre todos los archivos de Magento, por medio de la línea de comando o en tu IDE (PhpStorm, Sublime Text, etc.).

   Ejemplo: *product/view/attributes.phtml*
3. Luego entre esos resultados me deben aparecer algunos (o al menos uno) que provenga de un XML, el cual define los layouts de Magento. Posiblemente en el ejemplo que doy aparezca como resultado *catalog_product_view.xml* en el módulo de base Magento_Catalog.
4. A continuación miro en dicho archivo XML la línea donde este bloque es definido y por consiguiente encontraré su nombre o name, en la siguiente línea:

   ```
   <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" 
     name="product.attributes" as="additional" 
     template="product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
   ```

El nombre del bloque en este caso es **product.attributes**.

Aunque debes tener en cuenta que al momento de mover un elemento, en tu theme o en otra extensión con la etiqueta `<move>` puedes redefinir el alias del mismo:

```
<move element="product.attributes" as="nuevo.alias" destination="product.media"/>
```

---

Puedes revisar la documentación oficial de Magento 2 en cuanto a las tareas comunes de layout en el siguiente enlace:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html